# Data not being inserted in Table on Button Press

Tags: android, sqlite

When I tap the button for inserting the data it says it is successful, but when I check my listview there is no data. But If I add again, then only the data is inserted.

Why is the data only inserted on the second time?

Thanks in advance! :D

This is my Database Helper class:

```
 public static final String DB_NAME = "CartDB";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Orders";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String NAME ="name";
public static final String SIZE ="size";
public static final String QUANTITY ="quantity";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public cartDatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME + " VARCHAR, "
            + SIZE + " VARCHAR, "
            + QUANTITY + " VARCHAR);";

              db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST Orders";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addPerson(String name, String size, String quantity){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(SIZE,size);
    contentValues.put(QUANTITY,quantity);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}
```

And this is my MainActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alcohol_list);

    db = new cartDatabaseHelper(this);

  GridAlcoholAdapter adapter = new GridAlcoholAdapter(alcoholType.this, images, names);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                final int position, long id) {

   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String name = names.get(position);
                    String size = textSize.getText().toString().trim();
                    String quantityNumber = textQuantityNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                    String bottleCase = textBottleCase.getText().toString().trim();

                    String bottleCaseQuantity = textQuantity.getText().toString().trim();

                    textQuantity.setText(quantityNumber + " " + bottleCase);

                    db.addPerson(name,size,bottleCaseQuantity);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



     @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_cart:

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cartdialog);
            dialog.setTitle("YOUR CART");

            listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            final ListCartAdapter adapter = new ListCartAdapter(alcoholType.this, orderName, orderSize, orderQuantity);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            Cursor data = db.getListContents();
            data.moveToFirst();
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                orderName.add(data.getString(1));
                orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
                orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
            }
            data.close();

            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    orderName.clear();
                    orderSize.clear();
                    orderQuantity.clear();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter Class:

```
public class ListCartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;

private ArrayList<String> orderName;
private ArrayList<String> orderSize;
private ArrayList<String> orderQuantity;

public ListCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderName, ArrayList<String> orderSize, ArrayList<String> orderQuantity){
  // public ListCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderName){
    this.context = context;
    this.orderName = orderName;
    this.orderSize = orderSize;
    this.orderQuantity = orderQuantity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return orderName.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderName);
    TextView size = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderSize);
    TextView quantity = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderQuantity);

    name.setText(orderName.get(position));
    size.setText(orderSize.get(position));
    quantity.setText(orderQuantity.get(position));

    return listView;
}
```

Comment: Post your adapter please.

Comment: @GustavoConde I have added it sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is the data only inserted on the second time?**

The problem is in your `while` loop. When there is only `one` order then your `while` loop `body` will not be executed because you have used `data.moveToNext()` as condition. If your order count `more than one`, only then it will enter into the `while` loop.

**ERROR:**

```
data.moveToFirst();
while (data.moveToNext()) {
    orderName.add(data.getString(1));
    orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
    orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
if(data.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        orderName.add(data.getString(1));
        orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
        orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));

    } while(data.moveToNext());
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Yes sir you are correct :D I actually solved the problem and did it the same way you did, but since you still helped and it was the same answer as mine. I will accept your answer. 

Thanks sir!

Comment: Glad to know that and thanks for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because you are adding data to orderName,orderSize and orderQuantity after setting adapter to listView. and you are not even calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to let the adapter know that dataSet has changed

Comment: Sir I have a question, I have added a do-while into the code and it worked

   do{
                        orderName.add(data.getString(1));
                        orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
                        orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
                    } while (data.moveToNext());. Can you tell me why? haha

Comment: hey sir thanks again for the help! I really appreciate it :D and I will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: Because in that case data is being set first and then cursor is moving next after that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the adapter doesn't know that you have added an element to the database.

After:

`db.addPerson(name,size,bottleCaseQuantity);`

you should make

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Sir I have a question, I have added a do-while into the code and it worked

   do{
                        orderName.add(data.getString(1));
                        orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
                        orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
                    } while (data.moveToNext());. Can you tell me why? haha

Comment: I think it's because in a while loop, the condition gets checked before running the inside of the loop. So when you entered your while loop you where already in the second row of the table. Instead in a do while, you execute first, and then check the condition.

Comment: Oh okay sir. Atleast I have an insight on how to do it. Thanks again sir for the help and I will keep the adapter.notifydatasetchanged() in mind next time :D

Answer (score 0):

Well guys I fixed the problem

I made a do-while in retrieving the data and it works!

```
   do{
           orderName.add(data.getString(1));
           orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
           orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
                } while (data.moveToNext());
```

thanks again to anyone who wanted and helped :D

Comment: May I know the reason why you mark your answer as right answer instead of mine that you marked previously???

Comment: Sorry sir I was just checking and I forgot that it was marked already. I apologize for that sir. haha. I really thought that it was not answered haha.

Comment: Its OK. but don't do that in future. SO is tracking everything about the user actions. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes sir, I apologize again for that mis-understanding haha